# How to fix an 'undefined symbol error'?

Tags: fortran, intel, subroutine, fortran77, abaqus

I am quite new to both abaqus and fortran programming. I am working on a project where I am tying phase field to fracture propagation where the void phase is taken into the kinematics of the crack propagation. I will not go too much into detail!

I have attached 3 codes/messages with my question here:

a) umat_sdvini3.f (my user subroutine file that has both sdvini and umat in it)
b) Job-User-mod-9.inp (the .inp input file that I created with the help of Abaqus CAE)
c) Job-User-15.msg (the file that contains the error message!)

When I am telling Abaqus to run the job with the user subroutine, the job gets aborted for some reason! In the previous job runs (11 to 14), when in the subroutine file, the if/else statement for the state variable was commented out, everything ran fine!

With the second if/else statement uncommented in the attached fortran file, there is an error and the job is getting aborted!

The fortran 77 code for my user subroutine: (it is the second if/else statement command block not running properly! I thought I could access the values of the solution dependent state variables via coords(1) which is the x-coordinates!

```
  subroutine sdvini(statev,coords,nstatv,ncrds,noel,npt,layer,kspt)

  include 'aba_param.inc'

  dimension statev(nstatv), coords(ncrds)

  statev(1)=5.d0


  return
  end

  subroutine umat(stress,statev,ddsdde,sse,spd,scd,
 1 rpl,ddsddt,drplde,drpldt,
 2 stran,dstran,time,dtime,temp,dtemp,predef,dpred,cmname,
 3 ndi,nshr,ntens,nstatv,props,nprops,coords,drot,pnewdt,
 4 celent,dfgrd0,dfgrd1,noel,npt,layer,kspt,kstep,kinc)

  include 'aba_param.inc'

  character*80 cmname
  dimension stress(ntens),statev(nstatv)
  dimension ddsdde(ntens,ntens),ddsddt(ntens),drplde(ntens)
  dimension stran(ntens),dstran(ntens),time(2),predef(1),dpred(1)
  dimension props(nprops),coords(3),drot(3,3),dfgrd0(3,3),dfgrd1(3,3)

  C real E, xnu, bulk, shear

  integer i, j

  ddsdde = 0.d0

  E = props(1)
  xnu = props(2)

  statev(1)=5.d0

  shear = E/2.d0/(1.d0+xnu)
  bulk = E/3.d0/(1.d0-2.d0*xnu)

  real f_i=1.0e-10
  real w_bar=0.25d0
  real walpha=2.d0



  a_1 = (-2)*(1.d0-f_i)/0.25d0
  a_2 = (1.d0-f_i)/(0.25**2)

  C omega = statev(1)

  if(ndi.eq.2 .and. nshr.eq.1) then
    ddsdde(1,1) = bulk + (10.d0/9.d0)*shear
    ddsdde(1,2) = bulk - (8.d0/9.d0)*shear
    ddsdde(2,1) = bulk - (8.d0/9.d0)*shear
    ddsdde(2,2) = bulk + (10.d0/9.d0)*shear
    ddsdde(3,3) = 2.d0*shear
    ddsdde = ddsdde*statev(1)
  end if

  do i=1,ntens
    do j=1,ntens
        stress(i) = stress(i) + ddsdde(i,j)*dstran(j)
    end do
  end do

  if(coords(1).le.0 .and. coords(2).eq.0) then
    statev(1) = (w_bar*(1-tanh(w_alpha*coords(1))))
    statev(1)=1.d0+a_1*(statev(1))+a_2*(statev(1)**2)
  elseif(coords(1).gt.0 .and. coords(2).eq.0) then
    statev(1) = (w_bar*(1+tanh(w_alpha*coords(1))))
    statev(1)=1.d0+a_1*(statev(1))+a_2*(statev(1)**2)
  else
      statev(1)=0.d0
  end if

  statev(1)=state(1) + kinc

  write(6,*) ddsdde

  return
  end
```

This is the .inp file of the Abaqus (Standard):

```
  *Heading
  ** Job name: Job-User-9 Model name: Model-1
  ** Generated by: Abaqus/CAE 6.14-2
  *Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO
  **
  ** PARTS
  **
  *Part, name=Plate
  *Node
  1,           0.,         100.
  2,           0.,         99.5
  3,           0.,          99.
  4,           0.,         98.5
  5,           0.,          98.
  6,           0.,         97.5
  7,           0.,          97.
  8,           0.,         96.5
  9,           0.,          96.
 10,           0.,         95.5
 11,           0.,          95.
 12,           0.,         94.5
 13,           0.,          94.
 14,           0.,         93.5
 15,           0.,          93.
 16,           0.,         92.5
 17,           0.,          92.
 18,           0.,         91.5
 19,           0.,          91.
 20,           0.,         90.5
 21,           0.,          90.
 22,           0.,         89.5
 23,           0.,          89.
 24,           0.,         88.5
 25,           0.,          88.
 26,           0.,         87.5
 27,           0.,          87.
 28,           0.,         86.5
 29,           0.,          86.
 30,           0.,         85.5
 31,           0.,          85.
 32,           0.,         84.5
 33,           0.,          84.
 34,           0.,         83.5
 35,           0.,          83.
 36,           0.,         82.5
 37,           0.,          82.
 38,           0.,         81.5
 39,           0.,          81.
 40,           0.,         80.5
 41,           0.,          80.
 42,           0.,         79.5
 43,           0.,          79.
 44,           0.,         78.5
 45,           0.,          78.
 46,           0.,         77.5
 47,           0.,          77.
 48,           0.,         76.5
 49,           0.,          76.
 50,           0.,         75.5
 ...
 ...
 ...
 *Element, type=CPS4R
 1,     1,     2,   203,   202
 2,     2,     3,   204,   203
 3,     3,     4,   205,   204
 4,     4,     5,   206,   205
 5,     5,     6,   207,   206
 6,     6,     7,   208,   207
 7,     7,     8,   209,   208
 8,     8,     9,   210,   209
 9,     9,    10,   211,   210
10,    10,    11,   212,   211
11,    11,    12,   213,   212
12,    12,    13,   214,   213
13,    13,    14,   215,   214
14,    14,    15,   216,   215
15,    15,    16,   217,   216
16,    16,    17,   218,   217
17,    17,    18,   219,   218
18,    18,    19,   220,   219
19,    19,    20,   221,   220
20,    20,    21,   222,   221
21,    21,    22,   223,   222
22,    22,    23,   224,   223
23,    23,    24,   225,   224
24,    24,    25,   226,   225
25,    25,    26,   227,   226
26,    26,    27,   228,   227
27,    27,    28,   229,   228
28,    28,    29,   230,   229
29,    29,    30,   231,   230
30,    30,    31,   232,   231
31,    31,    32,   233,   232
32,    32,    33,   234,   233
33,    33,    34,   235,   234
34,    34,    35,   236,   235
35,    35,    36,   237,   236
36,    36,    37,   238,   237
37,    37,    38,   239,   238
38,    38,    39,   240,   239
39,    39,    40,   241,   240
40,    40,    41,   242,   241
41,    41,    42,   243,   242
42,    42,    43,   244,   243
43,    43,    44,   245,   244
44,    44,    45,   246,   245
45,    45,    46,   247,   246
46,    46,    47,   248,   247
47,    47,    48,   249,   248
48,    48,    49,   250,   249
49,    49,    50,   251,   250
50,    50,    51,   252,   251
...
...
...
*Nset, nset=Set-1, generate
 1,  40401,      1
*Elset, elset=Set-1, generate
 1,  40000,      1
** Section: Section-1
*Solid Section, elset=Set-1, controls=EC-1, material=Material-1
 1.,
*Hourglass Stiffness
 100., , 0., 0.
*End Part
**  
**
** ASSEMBLY
**
*Assembly, name=Assembly
**  
*Instance, name=Plate-1, part=Plate
*End Instance
**  
*Nset, nset=Left_edge, instance=Plate-1, generate
 1,  201,    1
*Elset, elset=Left_edge, instance=Plate-1, generate
 1,  200,    1
*Nset, nset=bottom-edge, instance=Plate-1, generate
 2211,  40401,    201
*Elset, elset=bottom-edge, instance=Plate-1, generate
 2200,  40000,    200
*Elset, elset=_Surf-1_S3, internal, instance=Plate-1, generate
 39801,  40000,      1
*Elset, elset=_Surf-1_S4, internal, instance=Plate-1, generate
 1,  39801,    200
*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=Surf-1
 _Surf-1_S3, S3
 _Surf-1_S4, S4
*End Assembly
** 
** ELEMENT CONTROLS
** 
*Section Controls, name=EC-1, hourglass=STIFFNESS
 1., 1., 1.
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
*Material, name=Material-1
*Depvar
  1,
*User Material, constants=2
 1e+06, 0.3
** 
*INITIAL CONDITIONS, TYPE=SOLUTION,USER
** BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
** 
** Name: BC-1 Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary
 Left_edge, 1, 1
** Name: BC-2 Type: Displacement/Rotation
*Boundary
 bottom-edge, 2, 2
** ----------------------------------------------------------------
** 
** STEP: Step-1
** 
*Step, name=Step-1, nlgeom=NO
*Static
1., 1., 1e-05, 1.
** 
** LOADS
** 
** Name: Load-1   Type: Pressure
*Dsload
Surf-1, P, -100.
** 
** OUTPUT REQUESTS
** 
*Restart, write, frequency=0
** 
** FIELD OUTPUT: F-Output-1
** 
*Output, field
*Node Output
CF, COORD, RF, U
*Element Output, directions=YES
E, S, SDV
** 
** FIELD OUTPUT: F-Output-2-bottomEdge
** 
*Node Output, nset=bottom-edge
COORD, U
*Element Output, elset=bottom-edge, directions=YES
S, SDV
** 
** HISTORY OUTPUT: H-Output-1
** 
*Output, history, variable=PRESELECT
*End Step
```

The .msg file is below: (I do not understand the error well!!! at all!!!)

```
Abaqus JOB Job-User-15
Abaqus 6.14-2
Abaqus License Manager checked out the following licenses:
Abaqus/Standard checked out 5 tokens from Flexnet server lm.rcc.psu.edu.
<255 out of 300 licenses remain available>.
Begin Compiling Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
Thu 13 Jul 2017 02:38:34 PM EDT
Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE for applications running on 
Intel(R) 64, Version 15.0.0.090 Build 20140723
Copyright (C) 1985-2014 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Intel(R) Fortran 15.0-1684
End Compiling Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
Begin Linking Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE for applications running on 
Intel(R) 64, Version 15.0.0.090 Build 20140723
Copyright (C) 1985-2014 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
ifort: command line remark #10148: option '-i-dynamic' not supported

GNU ld version 2.20.51.0.2-5.36.el6 20100205
End Linking Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
Thu 13 Jul 2017 02:38:35 PM EDT
Begin Analysis Input File Processor
Thu 13 Jul 2017 02:38:35 PM EDT
Run pre
Thu 13 Jul 2017 02:38:39 PM EDT
End Analysis Input File Processor
Begin Abaqus/Standard Analysis
Thu 13 Jul 2017 02:38:39 PM EDT
Run standard
/gpfs/apps/x86_64-rhel6/abaqus/6.14-2/6.14-2/code/bin/standard: symbol 
lookup error: /tmp/mfg5310_Job-User-15_1727/libstandardU.so: undefined 
symbol: state_
Thu 13 Jul 2017 02:38:43 PM EDT
Abaqus Error: Abaqus/Standard Analysis exited with an error - Please see the 
message file for possible error messages if the file exists.
Abaqus/Analysis exited with errors
```

Could any of you please help me with what it could be? Please!

Thank you,
Mousumi

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the error message, you have a typo at the undefined variable `state`.

```
statev(1)=state(1) + kinc
!! Should be:
statev(1)=statev(1) + kinc
```

It's possible the compiler didn't catch that error during compilation prior to runtime since you are using implicit typing (that is, not explicitly defining the variable types before using them). Perhaps you can verify that yourself.

Comment: That fixed it! I must say, intel is not great providing exact error messages!

Comment: good call, but note the compiler did catch that.. "undefined symbol: state_" (I'm really not sure how much more clear that error message could be?)

Comment: @agentp Right, the error msg states the problem clearly. But it wasn't caught during compilation prior to runtime, I'm guessing that's probably due to implicit typing. I clarified this is an edit, thx.

Comment: @MousumiG Glad to hear it! Would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: With implicit typing there's no problem to catch at compile time.  It's a link time problem with `state` being an external function.